# set time out not working with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to pause the javascript for a few seconds:

```
 setTimeout(start_countdown(),3000);
```

It does not work, the function is called regardless of the seconds. The following function does however work, which doesnt use a function.

```
setTimeout(alert('hi'),3000);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference. You are passing a function's return value.

The difference is this: one is a blueprint of the function you want to happen, the other means you are executing the function immediately and passing its return value to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(start_countdown, 3000);
```

If you want to do something more complex than simply call a named function, OR you want to pass a param to the named function, you'll need to instead pass an anonymous function to the timeout and call your function within that:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    start_countdown(/* possible params */);
    /* other code here as required */
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Can you explain why shouldn't we add parentheses as the first argument of the function `setTimeout`? I notice that if we add `()`, the function will fire immediately. Why is that?
I have no idea about how `setTimeout` actually works...

Comment: `setTimeout` registers an asynchronous event that will execute in (approximately) the number of milliseconds you specify. It expects as its first argument a FUNCTION - either a function literal or a reference to one specified elsewhere. If you pass a function name but with `()` after it, you are actually executing the function there and then, not asking the function to be called later. You need to learn the difference between function references and function invocation.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to pass params dont use ()

```
setTimeout(start_countdown,3000);
```

If you do you have to wrap your function

```
setTimeout(function(){start_countdown(parameter)},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

write instead

```
setTimeout(start_countdown, 3000);
```

without parens `()`
the second example could be also written as

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('hi'); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In different browsers it works in different way. In IE you need to use the anonymous function to pass the parameters to the callback:

> setTimeout(function(){alert('hi')},3000);