# Javascript onclick function is called immediately (not when clicked)?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to create a link, which looks and feels like an `<a>` tag item, but runs a function instead of using the href.

When I try to apply the onclick function to the link it immediately calls the function regardless of the fact that the link was never clicked. Any attempt to click the link thereafter fails.

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <a href="#" id="sendNode">Send</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
startFunction();

function secondFunction(){
    window.alert("Already called!?");
}

function startFunction() {
    var sentNode = document.createElement('a');
        sentNode.setAttribute('href', "#");
        sentNode.setAttribute('onclick', secondFunction());
      //sentNode.onclick = secondFunction();
        sentNode.innerHTML = "Sent Items";

    //Add new element to parent
    var parentNode = document.getElementById('parent');
    var childNode = document.getElementById('sendNode');
    parentNode.insertBefore(sentNode, childNode);
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52rcrww4/1/)

As you can see I tried two different ways of adding this onclick function, both of which have the same effect.

Comment: because you are calling it immediately `secondFunction()`, to pass a  function you just use its name `secondFunction`

Comment: This is a function invocation vs function reference issue. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757075/set-time-out-not-working-with-function/11757124#11757124

Comment: @PatrickEvans that's what I thought originally, but doing that doesn't run the function at all.

Comment: Then you need to look at your console for errors, for instance your jsfiddle is throwing an error because you have set it to have your code executed in the head and not using a dom ready event like onload

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want `.onclick = secondFunction`

**NOT** `.onclick = secondFunction()`

---

The latter calls (executes) `secondFunction` whereas the former passes a reference to the `secondFunction` to be called upon the `onclick` event

---

```js
function start() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", "#");
  a.onclick = secondFunction;
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("click me"));
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}

function secondFunction() {
  window.alert("hello!");
}

start();
```

---

You could also use [elem#addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
a.addEventListener("click", secondFunction);

// OR

a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  secondFunction();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @leigero — the code in JS Fiddle doesn't match the code in this answer

Comment: @leigero: Of course your fiddle doesn't work. The answer however works.

Comment: @leigero yes it does work. See the appended snippet.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid mistake that was only made complicated by trying to trouble shoot it in JsFiddle.