# on click function to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a script where an input field and button will be created based on selection of options. Now I want to execute a function upon clicking the button. Below is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="abc">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<div id="sd"> </div>
```

Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   i=0;
   $("#abc").on('change',function() {
   var maindiv= document.createElement('div');
       maindiv.setAttribute("id","TextBoxesGroup");
       var secdiv=document.createElement('div');
       secdiv.setAttribute("id","TextBoxDiv1")
       maindiv.appendChild(secdiv);
       var ipt=document.createElement("input");
       ipt.setAttribute("type","text");
       ipt.setAttribute("id","textbox1");
       secdiv.appendChild(ipt);
       var ad=document.createElement("input");
       ad.value= "+";
       ad.type="button";
       ad.style.width="30px";
       ad.setAttribute("id","addButton"+i);
       ad.onclick=fu_a(this.id);
       secdiv.appendChild(ad);    
       var division= document.getElementById("sd");
       division.appendChild(maindiv);
       i++;
    });
 });      

 function fu_a(id){
     alert(id);
 }
```

Here upon clicking on button function should get executed. But actually it's getting executed while changing option. Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/ssvjjg6e/16/

Comment: `ad.onclick = fu_a(this.id);` should be `ad.onclick = fu_a.bind(this.id);`

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526556/javascript-onclick-function-is-called-immediately-not-when-clicked

Comment: @Satpal Thanks. People usually wont delete an answer with upvotes. Thanks for leading by example.

Comment: Thanks everyone for response.

Comment: few pointers for you: 1. Look into `.addEventListener`, `.bind`, `.apply` and `.call`. 2. variables declared without `var` are global. 3. Use better naming convention(`id="sd"` does not shows purpose of element). 4. `document.ready` is an init function. It should call functions and not declare them. 5. Try to use smaller function and export common logic out to another function. That will make your code more readable and maintainable. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh for valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this

ad is your dynamically created button

```
ad.addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert("button clicked");
});
```

Comment: Though I would have advised the same, this does not explains why was it calling immediately. Also when you find an obvious question, there is a high possibility that it has been answer already. Best way is to find such posts and share their links for now. Later when you have enough rep, you can mark them as duplicate

Comment: yup but can't really do that with this kind of rep, i'm also new to SO

Comment: Yes I know. Thats why I said *find such posts and **share their links** for now*.